# How to plot the wave equation with fixed boundary

Tags: python, wave

I have tried to plot 3d wave equation with fixed boundary at z=0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def makeData ():
    x = np.arange (-10, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.arange (-10, 10, 0.1)
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zgrid=xgrid*2+ygrid**3
    return xgrid, ygrid, zgrid

x, y, z= makeData()
fig = pylab.figure()
axes = Axes3D(fig)
axes.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
pylab.show()
```

But I plot just a surface, where at boundary are different values. Also when I fixed boundary by its array, it wasn't a wave equation. Instead of this I got a broken line

My result

[image]

my expected figure

[image]

Comment: I have added figures to show my result

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure is the question is about the waves, or the z-range. The example below could address either:

- The waves with z=0 for x or y = +/- 10 is obtained with `zgrid = np.sin(xgrid*np.pi/10.) * np.cos(ygrid*np.pi*3/20.)`.
- The (close to) z=0 plane is displayed with `axes.set_zlim(0,3)`.

Complete code:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def makeData():
    x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
    xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    zgrid = np.sin(xgrid*np.pi/10.) * np.cos(ygrid*np.pi*3/20.)
    return xgrid, ygrid, zgrid

x, y, z= makeData()
fig = pylab.figure()
axes = Axes3D(fig)
axes.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet)
axes.set_zlim(0,3)
pylab.show()
```

[image: waves]

Comment: I think that the OP is asking something else, as you observe in the second image of the OP the plane z = 0 is the basis of the drawing even though there is data with z <0, and I think that is what the OP is looking for since in the first graph of the OP the base is the plane z = -1000.

Comment: @eyllanesc I see what you mean. I'm unsure which question OP was asking, I updated the example to cover both.